# Proper way to send JSON to Shopify across servers (Private App)

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, cross-domain, shopify

I am working with a private app on my Shopify store and am racking my brain trying to post JSON to my store via Ajax.

This is the data (sample)

```
var newCustomer = {
    "customer": {
        "first_name": "Steve",
        "last_name": "Lastnameson",
        "email": "steve.lastnameson@lastnamesonco.com",
        "verified_email": true,
        "addresses": [
          {
            "address1": "123 Oak St",
            "city": "Ottawa",
            "country": "CA",
            "first_name": "Mother",
            "last_name": "Lastnameson",
            "phone": "555-1212",
            "province": "ON",
            "zip": "123 ABC"
          }
        ]
      }
    };
```

And this is my Ajax call (Note: the url is not the one I use in the actual call)

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/resource.json",
    data: newCustomer,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(){console.log('Success');},
    failure: function(){console.log('Failure');}

});
```

This a cross domain call.

I do not get any results in my `console.log` at all.

Have any Shopify Users successfully done this?

[Here is some documentation on either a getting or posting from Shopify](http://docs.shopify.com/api/customer)

Comment: With a little more testing I see that the ajax call is not even being triggered, if I change the url to a local address, it gets triggered.

Comment: You should make an App that uses oAuth to authenticate to your store. At that point you'll have an easier time doing what you want. Not to mention, you do not want to use POST with your API key and password.

Comment: @DavidLazar This is strictly for a private app. The docs show this setup with the apikey and password in the url as the way to access admin capabilities from a remote server. See this page... http://docs.shopify.com/api/tutorials/creating-a-private-app Ultimately I want develop published apps yet I am not familiar with oAuth.  I am pretty fluent in php, js, jquery and mysql.

Comment: My point was simple. If you POST your JSON to the endpoint, it will work. There is no need to use Ajax. That is the source of your troubles.

Comment: @DavidLazar Ok thank you, And I do this how?

Comment: This thread seems to represent one server talking to another, and you seem fixated on using JS. Therefore I can only assume you're using NodeJS. To POST JSON to Shopify, you might want to use https://github.com/mikeal/request  Other than that, what you are trying to do remains difficult to figure out. Maybe if you explained your use case better... someone might help you.

Comment: @DavidLazar Hi Dave, I am actually not set on ajax at all. It was the basis of my question but I would be more than happy to use PHP.  I have found some info on using curl which I think is exactly what I am looking for. I do not know what nodeJS is. I need to post JSON though as of now Shopify Allows XML but it will be phased out. If you have any good, easy to understand resources for either creating JSON in PHP or how to POST using curl in PHP, I would greatly appreciate it.  I don't have any fancy setup here...pretty much Dreamweaver CC and some browser tools to help debug.

Comment: By all means use curl or PHP... there a million examples out there of how to do that!

Comment: I know it won't make you feel any better, but I just wrote about 10 lines of Ruby script that deleted 1100 customers, then re-imported them, sending the invite emails and tagging each customer with the word "Bumbledore". Scripting is great. No need for any Ajax.

Comment: @DavidLazar Yeah yeah yeah, one of my friends keeps telling me about ruby on rails, he does a ton of automation and database integration. I wouldn't even know where to begin. I love to script and develop neat little websites, but its not my main gig. He was telling me like a few words in ruby would create a complete customer table in a database...so jealous.